# Listbox of hyperlinks won't show clicked hyperlink as selected or current item

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a listbox with hyperlinks in one of my grid cells. When i click on any of the items in the listbox, the current item is always the first record in the listbox and the selected item is always null. Here is my WPF. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate.InputManagersList">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InputManagers}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock>                                    
                        <Hyperlink Name="inputManagerName" 
                           Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.OpenInputManagerViewCommand}"
                           CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}">
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ListBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.Style>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: How do you know what item is selected?  The ListBox does not even have a name.  Please post you code where to check selected item.

Comment: the parameter for my command method is a ListBox. So I just look at that object in my code. listBox.SelectedItem;

Comment: So you are not going to post that code?

Comment: I am not sure what code you want. The C# code is pretty minimal. I check my method parameter, which as you can see from the xaml above is the listBox itself. I then check listBox.SelectedItem. It is null. That is the sum total of the C# code.

Comment: That confirms you are not going to post the code where you get a null reference. Yet the question is about a null reference.  And not a single accepted answer.

Comment: Seriously??  listBox.SelectedItem IS THE NULL CODE. Seriously, the method is one line. var selectedItem = listBox.SelectedItem; selectedItem is equal to NULL. There really is nothing more to post. I am not sure why this is so difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please bind `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName}"` in List view object.

Comment: In Xaml? Where would that go in my above xaml?